# Parse XML in order using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML document.  The document has HTML like formatting embedded, for example

```
<p>This is a paragraph
 <em>with some <b>extra</b> formatting</em>
 scattered throughout.
</p>
```

So far I've used

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as xmlTree
```

to handle the XML document, but I am not sure if this provides the functionality I look for.  How would I go about handling the text nodes here?

Also, is there a way to find the closing tags in a document?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you studied the documentation for XMLTree?  By the time you load the document the concept of "closing tag" does not exist, as the document has been rendered into DOM nodes.  If you require access to the tags themselves you must use a SAX parser and handle start-tag and end-tag events yourself. However, since end tags can't have attributes it's not clear why you need access to them.

Comment: I'm new to Python and somewhat new to XML.  The XMLReader in PHP (a fetch reader that doesn't construct the complete tree) did give me the closing tags which I found very handy: I used the paired opening/closing tags and a stack to make sure that the XML document I received has its tags nested legally.

Comment: In that case, you want to use Python's SAX parser in the same way you used XMLReader in PHP.  I haven't worked with SAX in Python, but SAX uses an event-driven model where you get callbacks for start-tags, end-tags, attributes, text nodes, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the tip!  At the moment I tinker with BeautifulSoup but have spent more time extracting context than implementing a validator.  I think I might be able to build a soupy validator, but maybe just to learn I might use SAX for that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML document fits in memory, you should use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) which will give you a much cleaner access to the document. You'll be able to select a node and automatically interact with its children; every node will have a `.next` command, which will iterate through the text up to the next tag.

So:

```
>>> b = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup("<p>This is a paragraph <em>with some <b>extra</b> formatting</em> scattered throughout.</p>")

>>> b.find('p')
<p>This is a paragraph <em>with some <b>extra</b> formatting</em> scattered throughout.</p>

>>> b.find('p').next
u'This is a paragraph '

>>> b.find('p').next.next
<em>with some <b>extra</b> formatting</em>
```

That, or something like it, should solve your problem.

If it doesn't fit in memory, you'll need to subclass a SAX parser, which is a bit more work. To do that, you use `from xml.parsers import expat` and write handlers for opening and closing of tags. It's a bit more involved.

Comment: Trying to figure out how to make bs4 available for the MacPorts python 3.3 installation.  Can't seem to get this rolling...

Comment: pip is probably the easiest way to install Python packages like this.

Comment: There isn't any for the Python 3.3 available.

Comment: That took a while.  I uninstalled Python 3.3 (MacPorts) and then installed Python 3.2 and the py32-pip module.  I had to close the terminal, open a new one, then pip downloaded BeautifulSoup4 and I can reproduce your example nicely.  It looks like BS4 is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Just as a follow-up: I switched to using lxml for the better support of line numbers, XML schema and Xpath, large document support, and better and faster access to my XML document.  BS is nice, but too HTML oriented.  The Python lxml package does come with BS4 wrapped into it though.